# Highcharts Export Server: Too many requests

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I am trying to create a functionality of exporting a pdf, rendering the chart created using Highcharts in my webpage. I am using Highcharts' export server for creating chart image.

I am getting following error when I am trying to generate more than 30 chart images at a time.

```
Highchart response: http://export.highcharts.com/{ message : Too many requests, you have been rate limited. Please try again later.}): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

**EDIT:**
I found an option called `--ratelimit`. But it isn't specified how to use it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you're passing too many charts at once, or you reached some quota. I'd see about upgrading your license with them or contacting them. There's not much we can help you with since this isn't a specific programming problem.

Comment: There is an option called `--ratelimit`, but it is not specified how and where to use in their documentations.

Comment: The easy answer is to set up your own export server: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server or use client side exporting: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/client-side-export